# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I've seen the proof of the FTC in complex analysis but it doesn't really make sense to me. How can it be path independent? Why can I not change the value of the function on a particular path while leaving another path alone and thus change the integral value, while keeping the function continuous/integrable?

Comment: I think the complex case is easier when compared to the two variable real case. Path independient in both cases is the same, as you can use Green, Stokes and that in the real and imaginary functions of the complex one.

Comment: @Joanpemo I don't really understand stokes either tbh

Comment: @bww Haven't you studied advanced (multivariable) real analysis (calculus)?

Comment: Complex-differentiability is equivalent to analyticity. In a connected domain, you cannot 'change the value of the function on a particular path' since an analytic function is uniquely determined by its values on any set with an accumulation point in the domain, and in particular any given path.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yeah but not rigorously, it was just stated and we solved problems. Didn't really understand it intuitively.

Comment: @JonathanY. The function does not have to be differentiable to integrate it though? A non analytic continuous function would be sufficient

Comment: @bwv869 In fact you mainly need Green's theorem, and what happens when a vector field has a potential (or primitive) function, and how that affects line integrals.

Comment: bwv869, by the FTC I thought you were referencing Stokes' th. in the plane, i.e., $\int_\gamma f^\prime(z)dz = f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a))$?

Comment: @JonathanY. Oh right, I forgot that differentiable implies infinitely differentiable. So is path-independence not true for general integrable complex functions?

Comment: No, e.g. the well-known case of $\int_{S^1}\frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for the foundamental theorem of calcus in CA, is sensate take holomorphic functions in  simply connected domains. In a simply connected domain the integral of an holomorphic function is path indipendent. For istance:
Let $f: G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha , \beta$  two paths in $G$(a simply connected domain) with the same initial and final points , and with ounterclockwise orientation. We have  (Cauchy Theorem) $$\int_{\alpha - \beta}f(z)dz=0$$
then $0=\int_{\alpha -\beta}f(z)dz=\int_{\alpha}f(z)dz-\int_{\beta}f(z)dz \Rightarrow \int_{\alpha}f(z)dz=\int_{\beta}f(z)dz$ .